# Firestore beginTransaction REST API returns PERMISSION_DENIED when creating a readWrite transaction

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I need to update certain Firestore documents within transactions.

firestore.projects.databases.documents.beginTransaction fails when creating a readWrite transaction, but succeeds for a readOnly transaction.

I've ensured that the database is in test mode, with all reads and writes open

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if true;
        }
    }
}
```

(this fails)

https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/foo-bar-12345/databases/(default)/documents

```
    { 
        "options": {
            "readWrite": {}
        }
    }
```

error response:

```
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 403,
            "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.",
            "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
        }
    }
```

(this succeeds) - changing options to readOnly, returns a tranasaction

https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/foo-bar-12345/databases/(default)/documents

```
    { 
        "options": {
            "readOnly": {}
        }
    }
```

Successful response:

```
    {
        "transaction": "EcMecxy5IXKoIlkAIx+ixOCJ/NT6gvpbaEwWk/5YkOxVxSeMWpOdG4H2nZGK3Y0Pmcj+lbvk6sAlw68UpFgjd8puTpyS2Vwm2X6mw2SKKKKK9OakXxkGgi+8o4vx70Qd4YQaGg=="
    }
```

Comment: How are you authenticating your requests, Firebase Auth or Google OAuth? The security rules should only affect your request if you use Firebase Auth, https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization.

Comment: Thx Juan. The database is in test mode, completely open for reads and writes, so I'm not authenticating at all. I can successfully create, read, update or delete documents. The only thing I can't seem to do is create a readWrite transaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [beginTransaction](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/beginTransaction) REST API method does not support un-authenticated requests for `readWrite` transactions.

To atomically commit multiple un-authenticated writes, you can use the [commit](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/commit) method.

Comment: Ok, understood, regarding beginTransaction. thx
Regarding commit, I had been assuming I aways needed to pass in a transaction, when calling commit.

Comment: So is this the correct call flow, assuming I require transactions rather than just atomic commits:

1. beginTransaction (ensuring I'm authenticated) 
2. getDocument (passing in readWrite transaction from 1)
3. commit (passing in the transaction and including any updates)

Comment: Correct, and I believe you will have to authenticate with [Google OAuth](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/use-rest-api#working_with_google_identity_oauth_20_tokens) (instead of Firebase Auth).

Comment: No worries. Will do. Thx for your help

Comment: No problem, please upvote and accept if this helped you out :-)

Comment: @Juan Lara: Can you explain more why the using a firebase Auth token via Bearer does not work here? I run into the same issue and I try to send the Firebase Auth token as I do for other Firestore Rest APIs as a bearer in the header. Or is there a way to extend the scope of the Firebase Auth token?